# Setting the case status using the lightning component through the quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, component

I am trying to call the lightning Components from the Quick Action to change the status of Case to Closed on click of a button.

Components

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }" />
  <aura:attribute name="complete" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    fields="['CaseNumber','Status']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({ 
  recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    var caseRecord = component.get("v.record"),
      recordData = component.find("recordData");
      
      caseRecord.Status = 'Closed';
      
      if(!component.get("v.complete")) { // Avoid infinite loop
      component.set("v.complete", true);
      component.set("v.record", caseRecord);
      recordData.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
        if(result.state === "SUCCESS" || result.state === "DRAFT") {
          $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
          $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        } else { /* show an error here */ }
      }));
  }
  }})
```

But when I click on the Quick Action it throws error like

[image]

Not sure what I am missing here, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to set  mode="EDIT" for that like this

```
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    fields="['CaseNumber','Status']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    mode="EDIT"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer it helped. I am trying to fire a toast from the component it is not working posted the question here  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301107/toast-is-not-firing-from-the-lightning-component   Can you please help with this