# Toast is not firing from the lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, quickaction, toast

I am trying to show the toast on the screen after the field is updated using the lightning component the Controller looks like below

Controller

```
({ 
  recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    var caseRecord = component.get("v.record"),
      recordData = component.find("recordData");

      caseRecord.Status = 'Closed';

      if(!component.get("v.complete")) { // Avoid infinite loop
      component.set("v.complete", true);
      component.set("v.record", caseRecord);
      recordData.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
        if(result.state === "SUCCESS" || result.state === "DRAFT") {
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();   

          $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();


            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                title: "Success!",
                message: "Congrats, it works!",
                type: "success"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();          

        } else { /* show an error here */ }

      }));
  }
  }})
```

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }" />
  <aura:attribute name="complete" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    fields="['CaseNumber','Status']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    mode="EDIT"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

Everything else is working but I cannot see the Toast on the screen after it updated the field

Comment: try after removing $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();

Comment: Awesome that worked. Can we call the lightning component from the button as a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

and then fire toast and no i dont think you can launch component from button though you can open visual force page from button where you can call your component from there
here is the documentation on how you can do that
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm